# jQuery simple button bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, binding, bind

I'm new to jQuery, so this should be a simple question.

As far as I understand, I can bind a method to listen to an event, such as the click of a button, using

```
$('#buttonID').bind('click', function (){//some code});
```

However, this isn't working for me, so I must be doing something wrong.

This is my simple html file:

```
        <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js'></script>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js'></script>
    <script src='test.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <input id="SignIn" type="button" value="Sign In"></input>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Apart from loading jQuery files, it loads file test.js, which looks like this:

```
// JavaScript Document
$('#SignIn').bind('click', function() {alert('hi');});
```

Is that not enough for binding? I was hoping this would fire an alert dialog, but it doesn't, it seems the callback is not executed at all.

What is wrong here? Both files (html and js) are located in the same directory, and Google Chrome does not complain about anything in the JavaScript console, so from that end, everything should be fine.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: You need a `$(document).ready` function, read the documentation for jQuery, it's in almost every example, an is the first thing you'll learn.

Comment: Also, use `on`, not `bind`

Comment: @adeneo he is using jQuery 1.3.2 mate,

Comment: @BarlasApaydin - And that sound OK to you ? Then he should update!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your code in [**document ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler. It accepts a function which executes when DOM is fully loaded.

As you are using jQuery 1.3

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#SignIn').bind('click', function() {
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```

For jQuery 1.7+,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#SignIn').on('click', function() {
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```

Additionally, As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Comment: Ah yes, quick and simple answer. Thanks! Will mark as answer once SO allows me to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('#SignIn').bind('click', function() {alert('hi');});
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function(){
   $('#SignIn').click(function() {alert('hi');});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your Javascript to the bottom of the HTML page, right above the closing body tag.

That way the DOM is ready when it is loaded, and there's no need for `$(document).ready()` calls.

https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Answer (score 1):

You may want to include your `JavaScript` files at the very bottom, and everything should work as expected. It is recommended to do this and to include `CSS` files at the top (head tag). For more information see link included by @Grim...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<input id="SignIn" type="button" value="Sign In"></input>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js'></script>
<script src='test.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {

//Write some code here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#SignIn').on('click', function() {alert('hi');});

});
```

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and why this solves the problem by editing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

- `$(document).ready(function () {
         $("#SignIn").click(function () {
          alert('demo');
        });
  });`

Comment: #user2606742 - If answer is useful, Please click on 'correct' and give 'upvote' so it will helps other to find out correct solution.